# A question about scaling in optimization problem

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

For example, if I want to maximize
$f(x) = x^2+xy $ subject to constraints such like $x+y=5$

Can I scale the target function or the constraints as I want?
Like $ L = \frac{1}{2}(x^2+xy) - \lambda\times\frac{65535}{8787}(x+y-5)$

Would that change the explainability of Lagrange Multipliers or the result of the optimization problem?

Comment: Such scaling has no effect on the  optimum found by the Lagrange multiplier method. At most, what will change is the value of the multiplier $\lambda$.

Comment: If you're using the Lagrange multiplier for sensitivity analysis, you won't get the correct sensitivity after such a scaling.